# Passing an Array of object results in errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an API in ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework as per below sample

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult AddInvoiceRest([FromBody]AddInvoiceRetailRest[] InvoiceDetail)
{
}
```

here `AddInvoiceRetailRest` is class object. I want to pass multiple objects as array.

I am doing testing with postman. I have passed this array from raw body as per below sample.

```
{
  "InvoiceDetail": [
    {
      "InvoiceMst": [
        {
          "InvoiceNo": 0,
          "CustId": 0,
          "SubTotal": 93,
          "TaxAmount": 13
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

problem is here in api i received blank array without adding **[Frombody]** and when i add **[FromBody]** , Api doesn't call and shows error like below

```
{
    "InvoiceDetail": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

definition of class is

```
public class AddInvoiceRetailRest   
    {
        public AddInvoiceMst[] InvoiceMst { get; set; }
        public AddInvoiceItemDetail[] InvoiceItemDetail { get; set; }
        public AddInvoicePaymentDetail[] InvoicePaymentDetail { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public AddInvoiceItemLogDetail[] InvoiceItemLog { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public string BillDetail { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public PumpCartObject[] InvoicePumpCart { get; set; }
        [Optional]
        public InvoiceFeeOrDeposite[] InvoiceFeeOrDeposite { get; set; }
    }
```

Here in the question, I just put a sample of the request, not all keys.
Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @mororo received blank array. doesn't receive data,

Comment: You don't need `{""InvoiceDetail"":` in start and `}` in end

Comment: Can you please post the AddInvoiceRetailRest class definition? I see double square brackets and was wondering if any collection is present in class definition

Comment: @mororo yeah. actually here in question i just have posted sample. let me edit question and post full defination

Comment: InvoiceItemDetail is not marked as Optional and you're not passing it. Could be that?

Comment: @mororo actually i am passing it. here in sample i just did not passed in question only.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i did same also but still not getting data in array. its blank array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are expecting array in your API but you are passing a single object json and not an array.

Try this:

```
[
    {
        "InvoiceMst":
        [
            {
                "InvoiceNo": 0,
                "CustId": 0,
                "SubTotal": 93,
                "TaxAmount": 13
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. it is working. basically my main problem was i was passing InvoiceDetail key name with { } bracket. it was not required, Thanks a lot brother, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @AbhijitPandya, It wasn't just the keyword. Your json starts with { which means that you are trying to pass a single object rather than an array. It needs to start with [ which is an array.

Answer (score 2):

The posted data does not match the expectation of the action.

One option is to create a model that matches the expected data

```
public class InvoiceDetailModel {
    public AddInvoiceRetailRest[] InvoiceDetail { get; set; }
}
```

And bind to that in the action

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult AddInvoiceRest([FromBody]InvoiceDetailModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        AddInvoiceRetailRest[] invoiceDetail = model.InvoiceDetail;

        //...
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```